# Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Request::header()

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel. I have a controller where I just want to get the value of `Authorization` from the header.  I saw other stack overflow answers that suggest I use `$request->header('Authorization')`.  But doing so gave me the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Request::header()
```

I could use `getallheaders()` from PHP, but prefer to use any available laravel methods for this.  Can someone tell me how to get header information with laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling `$request->header(...)` and getting that error that means that `$request` is an instance of the Facade not the Request class. You don't use instances of Facades, they are **only** static proxies.

If you want an instance of the Request you would be using `Illuminate\Http\Request`. `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` is the static proxy for the bound instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.html#method_header). The method header you used is in the class Illuminate\Http\Request. So you need to import it.